# Boundary length of two growing circles

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, circles

Two circles are separated by a distance d and grow radially outwards. Over time, this creates an ‘impinged’ boundary.

[image: [.gif]]

How do you calculate the length of the boundary without simulation?

I thought about using the circle-circle intersection formula:

$$a=\frac{1}{d}\sqrt{4 d^{2} R^{2}-\left (d^{2}-r^{2}+R^{2}  \right )^2}$$

Then saying R and r are functions of time R(t) and r(t), then taking its partial derivative with respect to R and r. Then solving numerically when R(t) and r(t) are known. But I’m not sure if that is going anywhere?

I saw in this paper https://doi.org/10.1016/S1359-6454(99)00376-6 around eqn 4 a chord construction may be possible but I'm not sure it would work for the case of curved boundary?

Comment: "Two circles are separated by a distance d and grow radially outwards. When their boundaries meet, they stop growing at that point."  Your animation doesn't show that.

Comment: My apologies, I've changed the opening sentence.

Comment: A curve with constant difference of distances to two fixed points is a hyperbola, and its length is not going to be nice at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That boundary is described by the intersection points of the circles, while their radii grow. Set up a coordinate system such that the center of the left circle is at $O=(0,0)$, while the center of the right circle is at $C=(d,0)$, and let $P(t)$ be the intersection point having $y\ge0$. Then $OP=R(t)$ and $CP=r(t)$ are given and $\angle COP=\theta(t)$ can be computed with the cosine law:
$$
\cos\theta(t)={R^2(t)-r^2(t)+d^2\over2dR(t)}.
$$
The length of the boundary is then:
$$
L(t)=2\int_{t_0}^t\sqrt{R^2(s)\,\dot{\theta\hspace{0pt}}^2(s)+\dot{R}^2(s)}\,ds,
$$
where $t_0$ is the time the circles meet for the first time.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!